# Is bootstrap 4 stable? Is it still in development?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Hey guys is bootstrap four stable? It seems as if its still in development and they were doing bug fixes as early as this year. Is it feasible to use it on a production site with many customers or should I stick to my roots in bootstrap 3?

Comment: Bootstrap v4.0.0 released [in January](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/01/18/bootstrap-4/). Improvements and bug fixes are being done continuously but it's far out of beta. I advise you to read over the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/), try out (test) the features which are required by your website, and decide based on your experiences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your asking for an opinion, which is not the purpose of this site. 
(Hence the negative votes on your question)

That said, Bootstrap 4 is out of beta, production release is currently v4.1.1

Is it right for your situation? No clue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I'm kinda new at this and stuff

Comment: No worries, I made the same mistake.  ; )